# Cell Value Checking and Comparison

Tags: excel

I am wondering if there is a formula I can use for the following requirements:

I have a 3 sheet excel file (sheet 1,2,3)

**On sheet 3 : I want to have a formula that checks specific cell values on other sheets and gives me a summary of results (basically a verification sheet).**

Examples of what I need checked :

Cell A1 on Sheet 1 >= Cell B2 on Sheet 2

Cell A1 on Sheet 1 = Cell A2 on Sheet 1

If these conditions are satisfied, I want the formula to output the word "Verified". If not, then it should say "Condition not Satisfied".

Thank You :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what you are looking for:

```
=IF(AND(Sheet1!A1>Sheet2!B2,Sheet1!A1=Sheet1!A2),"VERIFIED","CONDITION NOT SATISFIED")
```

Make sure you understand what AND and IF functions do.

Comment: Tried this but it says there is an error in the formula...Also, I was looking to split this formula =IF(AND(Sheet1!A1 > Sheet2!B2);"VERIFIED";"CONDITION NOT SATISFIED")

Comment: @Adam: try the edited formula (with commas instead of semi-colons)

Comment: Thanks JMax. That worked. One more question: If I want to check a range of cells how would I modify this to do that? I tried this but it did not work : =IF(AND(Sheet1!C64:J64=Sheet2!C33:J33),"Yes","No")

Comment: Thanks for editing my post JMax. I have an English MS Office, but the system is Dutch. That is why it looked the way it looked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the cell on the other sheet, by including the name of the sheet in the forumula. Other than that, formulas between sheets work pretty much the same as formulas within the same sheet.

For example:

```
=Sheet1!A1 + A2
```

...will add the values of cells `A1` and `A2` on `Sheet1`.

Ref: http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/me/mes12p2.html

Also, this is more of a question for [superuser.com](https://superuser.com/) - I've voted to move it there.